# Declare class attributes inside a for loop in python

Tags: python, class, attributes, attributeerror, declare

Im trying to create a game which is a rip off of Clash of Clans. The first thing to do is create classes for troops and spells used during the attacking phase. I have defined a class Troop which is a general class, and the idea is all its attributes will be overwritten when declaring specific troops.
Here is the barebone Troop class

```
class Troop():
    def __init__(self):
        self.fav_target = 'any'
        self.damage_type = 'single' #or 'area'
        self.targets = 'ground'
        self.space = 1
        self.speed = 1
        self.dps = 1
        self.hp = 1
        self.type = 'ground' #or 'air'
        self.level = 1
        self.attack_rate = 1
```

Clash of clans has many troops and each troops attributes (like hp, dps) change with the level. For now i have only implemented those attributes for the highest possible level. 
To save all the attribute values for specific troops, i have declared dictionaries. Here is the attribute dictionary for a "Barbarian" troop. The format is `{'<troop lvl>': {'<attr>': <value>}}`

```
barbs = {'9': {'fav_target': 'any', 'damage_type': 'single', 'targets': 'ground', 'space': 1, 'speed': 16, 
        'dps': 38, 'hp': 230, 'type': 'ground', 'attack_rate': 1}}
```

Instead of manually overwriting each attribute inside the barbarian class, i thought to use a for loop to overwrite all the attributes inside the barbarian class, like this:

```
class Barbarian(Troop):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Barbarian, self).__init__()
        self.name = 'Barbarian'
        for attr in barbs['9']:
            self.attr = barbs['9'][attr]
```

Problem is when I print Barbarian.hp, it return the value inside the Troop class instead of the Barbarian class. If I remove the super() statement, then printing something like Barbarian.hp gives an AttributeError.

Is there a way to overwrite (or declare) attributes inside a class inside a for loop?

Comment: Are you looking for setattr perhaps? Is there any reason why you declare the features on a dict, then copy them to a class, instead of declaring them on the class directly? Alternatively, why doesn’t Troop.__init__ take all features as parameters, and you pass them in as ˋ**kwargsˋ?

Comment: doing `self.attr` set an attribut with name *attr" not its the value at the time of the loop

Comment: use `setattr(self, attr, barbs['9'][attr])`

Comment: The normal procedure would be to have all keywords passed to the _init__ method and process them from there. You only need to subclass if you add attributes in Brabarian which are not included in Troop already. You can also use the **kwargs syntax and loop through kwargs in your __init__ routine. But it seems that you should first read more about object oriented programmig in Python.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. The reason the features are initially declared in a dict, and then copied to a class is because in this instance, i have only used lvl9 barbs. but in the final implementation there will be lvls 1 through 9, and only 1 of them will be created as a barbarian object based on an input by the user.
The kwargs thing makes sense, but from an implementation standpoint i cant tell if that will make life easier or harder in the future. 
Regarding the setattr, thank you so much, it worked and it is the exact thing i needed in this situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a [`**kwargs`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument) parameter; use [setattr](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#setattr) in `__init__`; pass a dictionary to the instance.

```
class Barbarian(Troop):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Barbarian, self).__init__()
        self.name = 'Barbarian'
        for attr,value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self,attr,value)

b = Barbarian(**barbs['9'])
```

Comment: Yes this works perfectly. The setattr is what i needed for this. Thank you so much!